Not sure why script running but doesn't give output?
New beginner here for python and ı have sense of basics of python. I was trying to learn OOP details by following a tutorial then ı realized when ı run my code on VScode. It doesn't give me anything back. I just gives me back the filepath. I am not sure what to do. I tried adding print to see if anything comes out but nope!
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} should be greater or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} should be greater or equal to zero!"


        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    
item1 = Item("Phone", 100, 1)
item2 = Item("Laptop", 1000, 3)
item3 = Item("Cable", 10, 5)
item4 = Item("Mouse", 50, 5)
item5 = Item("Keyboard", 75, 5)

enter image description here
Well that is how it looks

This code declares several Item objects, but it doesn't print anything.  What output, exactly, were you expecting to see?  The only possible output would be if one of the assert conditions failed, but none of them do.

Try this:
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} should be greater or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} should be greater or equal to zero!"


        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def show_total_price(self):
        price = self.calculate_total_price()
        print('Price: ', price)

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate


item1 = Item("Phone", 100, 1)
item1.show_total_price()
item2 = Item("Laptop", 1000, 3)
item3 = Item("Cable", 10, 5)
item4 = Item("Mouse", 50, 5)
item5 = Item("Keyboard", 75, 5)

Function show_total_price() will show the price of the item.
You can run it again and check its output.
The output will be like this:
Price: 100

If you still can’t see the output, perhaps you’ll need to check your CPython interpreter and other things.
